# "Sleep" and keep processes running

Tags: linux, xorg, kde, suspend, lightdm

Is there a way I can do what sleep does:

1. Turn off all the computer lights
2. Turn off the fans
3. Turn off the display
4. Lock the DE

but without suspending processes to ram? Would I need to script this or such a utility already exists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd need to script this. Well, you can typically set a lock screen program (whichever you're using, you're using multiple conflicting tags there), to turn off the screen (if you can't, `xset` is your friend).

But turning off fans makes no sense (if they are adjustable by software, they should already only be spinning when there's need for cooling – so if they spin, you need to leave them spinning or risk that your CPU overheats).

Turning off computer lights: Do you mean like RGB lights on your keyboard? In that case, you'd need to use openRGB (or whatever you use to control these) to tell the thing to turn off the lights.

Comment: The fans actually run continuously until shutdown or sleep, there is a manual setting for them on the case

Comment: yeah but a manual switch is not software-controlled.

Comment: Ofcourse, but can't the fans be controlled by the software? The switch is handy, but when I put the computer to sleep they stop. So software must have some control over them

Comment: I don't know your hardware. On some systems they can, on some they can't be controlled by software under your control (that they stop when suspended: no surprise, that's a fimrware functionality which necessarily involves shutting down power rails, anyways). But no matter which applies: you can only turn off fans that you don't acutely need, and since these don't turn off by themselves, a reasonable assumption is that you cannot just turn them off while the system is still producing heat.